# Jquery dynamically created droppable elements don't Work

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, droppable, jquery-ui-droppable

Well,Hello folks I developed a page to create forms drag and drop, but I'm having trouble with the drop of internal elements, eg:

```
<div class="container">
   <div classs="row"> <! - I drop here -!> </ div>
   <- Content is dropped here! : '(-!>
</ div>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){

                $( "#a .row-element" ).draggable({ 
                    revert: "invalid",
                });

                $(  "#a .span2-element" ).draggable({ 
                    revert: "invalid",
                });

                $(".row").droppable({
                    accept: '.span2-element',
                    activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
                    hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
                    greedy: true,
                    drop: function(event, ui) {
                        $('<div class="span2"></div>"').appendTo(this);
                    },
                    activate: function(event, ui) {
                        $(ui.helper).draggable({ revert: "valid"});
                    }
                });

                $(".container").droppable({
                    accept: '.row-element , .span2-element',
                    activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
                    hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
                    greedy: true,
                    drop: function(event, ui) {
                        $('<div class="row"></div>"').appendTo(this);
                    },
                    activate: function(event, ui) {
                        $(ui.helper).draggable({ revert: "valid"});
                    }
                });
        });
```

It seems to me that the newly created element is not dropavel ... :/

Any suggestions?! thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, make sure your HTML code is :

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

Then, why do you have :

```
$('<div class="span2"></div>"').appendTo(this);
```

You should have :

```
 $('<div class="span2"></div>').appendTo(this);
```

Comment: What a mistake on my part! : The

Well, still not working, it seems that it ignores the "$ (". Row "). Droppable ()".

When I create the appentTo in an html element, I need to use dropplable again?

Comment: I make a change:

    <div id ="c">
     <div class="row"></div> 
     <div class="span2"></div> 
    </div>

    #c{
     width:1px;
     height:1px;
    }    

    $('#c .row').clone().appendTo(this);
    
    
    Now, my div have ui-droppable class, but don't work! :/

Comment: Can you please post your development URL so I can check ?

Comment: I'm able to drop elements.. I'm on FF and I get no problem ! Can you please clear your browser cache ?

Comment: Me too! :D
Thx bro!

But the drop only work to rows... span don't work. I try make rows work in rows, but don't work again... 

I try in firefox, Chrome, Opera e IE9... Any Suggest? ^^

Comment: All divs with class .span2-element are dropable... Can you please put your HTML code in http://bot-socialpu.rhcloud.com/editor/, so I can try to check why you get this error ?